# How do I get this random selector game to repeat and count the results?

Tags: javascript, loops, counter, simulation

I have this variation on the Monty Hall Problem where instead of picking and switching/not switching, it is done randomly.

I supposedly have learned enough to be able to create this so that the random selector repeats 100 times, and outputs a win count and a loss count, however I'm stuck at the beginning. All I've been able to show is that it successfully selects randomly, but don't know how to go about getting it to repeat 100x and count the results. I'm assuming I need to use a while loop and winCount++ but have no idea how to go about making this work.

Appreciate any help!

```
//define prizes
//1 is a win
var prizes = [1,2,3];
var winCount = 0;
var loseCount = 0;

//copy prizes array so can be reused
var choices = prizes.slice();

//randomly select a prize
var pick1 = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];

//find index of pick1
var pick1Index = choices.indexOf(pick1);

//remove an item that is not the win or pick1

function removePrize(choices,pick1){
    var prizeRemoved = Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length);
    if(choices[prizeRemoved]==pick1){
        return removePrize(choices,pick1);
    }
    else if (choices[prizeRemoved]==1){
        return removePrize(choice,pick1);}
    else{
        return prizeRemoved;
    }
};

//randomly re-select from remaining prizes
var pick2 = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];


//display pick2 to show selector works
alert(window["pick2"]);
```

Comment: What do you need to repeat percisely?

Comment: The whole process of pick1 and removing a prize and re-picking. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can encapsulate the process of picking an item from the choices in a function and then call the function in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I've moved the code to a jsfiddle with the solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/dwthz8v1/2/ and have console logged the output, press f12 to take a look at the console, I believe the working code you are looking for is this:

```
//define prizes
//1 is a win
var prizes = [1,2,3];
var winCount = 0;
var loseCount = 0;
var totalGames = 100;

for(var i = 0; i < totalGames; i++) {
   //copy prizes array so can be reused
  var choices = prizes.slice();
   //randomly select a prize
  var pick1 = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
  var pick1Index = choices.indexOf(pick1);


    var removedPrize = removePrize(choices, pick1);
  var indexOfPrizeToRemove = choices.indexOf(removedPrize);
  //remove prize from choices
  choices.splice(indexOfPrizeToRemove);

  //remove pick1 from choices
  choices.splice(indexOfPrizeToRemove);

  var pick2 = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];

  if(pick2 == 1) {
    console.log("Pick 2 won!");
    winCount++;
  }
  else {
    console.log("Pick 2 was wrong");
    loseCount++;
  }
}

console.log("Pick 2 won a total of " + winCount + " times");
console.log("Pick 2 lost a total of " + loseCount + " times");


//find index of pick1
var pick1Index = choices.indexOf(pick1);

//remove an item that is not the win or pick1

function removePrize(choices,pick1){
    var prizeRemoved = Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length);
    if(choices[prizeRemoved]==pick1){
        return removePrize(choices,pick1);
    }
    else if (choices[prizeRemoved]==1){
        return removePrize(choices,pick1);}
    else{
        return prizeRemoved;
    }
};
```

The way it works is by looping 100 times in a for loop. Each iteration represents an individual game.

You set up the choices array for each game. Make a choice, then remove a choice, then show how many times switching the choice won and how many times switching the time lost